# Quick Select Clarification

Tags: algorithm, select, quickselect

What is exactly meant by "**k**" in this lecture slide of Quick Select?

[image]

Comment: The Element you are searching for is the kth smallest element in the array

Comment: Can you explain the equations with "k"? Thanks!

Comment: |L| is just size (length) of L subarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you took a number `x`.

Let `L` be the set of numbers less than `x` in the array, size of the set is `|L|`

Let `E` be the set of numbers equal to `x` in the array, size of the set is `|E|`

Let `G` be the set of numbers larger than `x` in the array, size of the set is `|G|`

Let's imagine the sorted array, the first `|L|` numbers `(1 -> |L|)` are contained in set `L`.

The following `|E|` numbers `(|L|+1 -> |L|+|E|)` are contained in set `E`.

The following `|G|` numbers `(|L|+|E|+1 -> end)` are contained in set `G`.

We are looking for the `kth` smallest number, so we have 3 cases:

1) `k <= |L|` this means that the number we are looking for is in the first `|L|` numbers in the sorted array, so we search for the `kth` smallest number in `L`.

2) `|L| < k <= |L|+|E|` this means that the number we are looking for is in a position between `(|L|+1 -> |L|+|E|)` in the sorted array, so it is an element from `E`. Since all elements of `E` are equal to `x`, we know that the `kth` smallest number is equal to `x`.

3) `k > |L|+|E|` this means that the number we are looking for is in a position between `(|L|+|E|+1 -> end)` in the sorted array, so it is an element from 'G'. Since there are already `|L|+|E|` numbers less than the `kth` smallest number, we can subtract `|L|+|E|` from `k`, let's call it `k'` (`k' = k - |L| - |E|`), and search for the `k'th` smallest element in `G`.